# Python: How to merge duplicate rows only if they are exactly similar in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with columns `Items` and `Ranges`.

```
      Items  Ranges
0     A      30
1     A      30
2     A     -10
3     B      20
```

I want to merge duplicate rows and add the range values but only for the rows that are exactly the same. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
          Ranges
Items        
A          60
A         -10
B          20
```

I tried `df2 = df1.groupby(['Items']).sum()` and I am getting the result as:

```
          Ranges
Items        
A          50
B          20
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can groupby and aggregate like:

```
df.groupby(['Items', 'Ranges'], as_index=False).agg({'Items': 'first', 'Ranges': 'sum'})
```

Output:

```
  Items  Ranges
0     A     -10
1     A      60
2     B      20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` both columns, and then `droplevel` with 'Ranges' (level 1) in the index:

```
df.groupby(['Items', 'Ranges'])['Ranges'].sum().droplevel(1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Items  Ranges
0     A     -10
1     A      60
2     B      20
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group them not only by item but also by range. Remember that the items you group after grouping have multiple values. Since you grouped, you have only one single item. So you have to take into account what will happen to the corresponding multiple values. For this, you should use the aggregate function. I recommend you to check the link.

[pandas-aggregate document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html)